# Hide Android "voice to Text" Dialog Box

Tags: android

I am working with an Voice to Text Application where I need to keep Voice command Dialog in background, means I don't want to hide it again n again.

Pls shows me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible
 (unless you hack into a rooted phone)

Answer (score 0):

What might help you is to increase the time allowed for the RecognitionListener to wait until it considers the input complete. You can control that with the `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` flag.

And from your question it sounds like you are showing the voice command dialog. If you don't want to do that, consider taking a look at [this](https://www.varvet.com/blog/voice-to-text-arch-android/) blogpost, showing how to control your interface your self (and using android architecture components to drive the voice updates).